# How to add label programmatically and position it with auto layout programmatically

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uilabel, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I'm trying add a label to a UIScrollView. I'm adding a top constraint and a leading constraint.
The label is not appearing.

Here is my code.

```
   self.label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40)];
    self.label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    self.label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    self.label.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    self.label.text = @"Hello";
    [self.imageCarouselScrollView addSubview:self.label];
    [self bringSubviewToFront:self.label];
    self.titleLabelTopConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint
                                    constraintWithItem:self
                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                    relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                    toItem:self.imageCarouselScrollView
                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                    multiplier:1.0
                                    constant:20];
    NSLayoutConstraint *titleLeadingConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint
                                                  constraintWithItem:self
                                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                  relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                  toItem:self.imageCarouselScrollView
                                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                                  multiplier:1.0
                                                  constant:20];
    [self addConstraints:@[self.titleLabelTopConstraint,titleLeadingConstraint]];
```

Comment: Have you tried to see if the `UILabel` shows with out the constraints added? And, not trying to be funny.. your views background color isn't set to white is it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to include a constraint to the right (for horizontal scrolling) or bottom (for vertical scrolling) of the scroll view so that it can deduce the content size.

Answer (score 0):

I try comment your code:

```
    self.label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40)]; //if 'translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=NO' frame not work work anymore. Use CGRectZero instead
    self.label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    self.label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    self.label.textColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    self.label.text = @"Hello";
    [self.imageCarouselScrollView addSubview:self.label]; //Your self.label added on 'self.imageCarouselScrollView' but your constraints added on self
    [self bringSubviewToFront:self.label]; // ??? Why?
    self.titleLabelTopConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint
            constraintWithItem:self
                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                     relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                        toItem:self.imageCarouselScrollView
                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                    multiplier:1.0
                      constant:20]; //it constrain means: "self view top edge equal to self.imageCarouselScrollView bottom + offset 20 "
    NSLayoutConstraint *titleLeadingConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint
            constraintWithItem:self
                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                     relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                        toItem:self.imageCarouselScrollView
                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                    multiplier:1.0
                      constant:20];//it constrain means: "self view Leading edge equal to self.imageCarouselScrollView Trailing + offset 20 "
    [self addConstraints:@[self.titleLabelTopConstraint,titleLeadingConstraint]];
```

And now i have few questions:

1. Why constraints for self.label?? Because after translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=no it frame equals 0; You didn't see label anymore.
2. You have 2 constraints what about other edges????
3. No question, council, try use 'constraintsWithVisualFormat:options:metrics:views:'

Comment: With labels you only two constraints to determine its x value and y value then its width and height will based on its content. I haven't really tried constraintWithVisualFormat.

Comment: @user1898829 `sizeToFits` not work more with autolayouts, learn `setContentHuggingPriority:forAxis:` and `setContentCompressionResistancePriority:forAxis:`